# Configuración Stylus - Gulp (v4) -

Tags: gulp, stylus, gulp-4

Me podéis hechar un cable con la configuracion del gulpfile.js.? Llevo días con esto pero no hay manera de que funcione la config de Babel. Aquí os dejo el ficheros.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.
:)

**gulpfile.js**

// .require

```
const gulp          = require('gulp');
const uglify        = require('gulp-uglify');
const rename        = require("gulp-rename");

const concat        = require('gulp-concat');
const babel         = require('gulp-babel');
const plumber       = require('gulp-plumber');

const browserSync  = require( 'browser-sync' ).create();
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
```

// .js

```
 gulp.task('js', function(){
   return gulp.src(paths.sources.js)
   .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
   .pipe(plumber())
   .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
    }))
  .pipe(concat('main.js'))
  .pipe( uglify({ mangle: false }).on('error', function(e)
   {
     console.log('Error uglify: ' + e); 
  }))
  .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
  .pipe( sourcemaps.write( paths.destinations.js ) )
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.destinations.js))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});
```